# How to make Super/Base/Parent class in microservices in spring-boot - to extend that class in child class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices

**1)**
I have 3 microservices project (Country-micro, State-micro and City-micro) with 3 entities Country, State and City in each microservices define respectively. Please note that all 3 microservices has same group id in pom.xml

All the entity has common 4 fields

1. id
2. created_date
3. modified_date
4. is_active

How can I make base entity class for above fields and use it in different microservices. Like, in monolithic architecture we can use easily by extending class as define here :

My base Class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
public class BaseEntity {
    private Long id;
    private Date created_date;
    private Date modified_date;
    private Boolean is_active;

}
```

My child class

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@Table(name="tbl_country")
public class Country extends BaseEntity {
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;
}
```

But, in microservices architecture, all entities are separated. Then, how can I define service to make as Super class.

**2)** With the same question above, I also want to use my constant class in each microservices. Like, in monolithic structure, we can :

```
public interface Constants {
    static String HTTP = "http";
    static String COMMA_AND_SPACE = ", ";
}
```

And can use this constants in any class like:

```
public String myMethod(MyDto myDto) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("My First String").append(Constants.COMMA_AND_SPACE);
    sb.append("My Second String").append(Constants.COMMA_AND_SPACE);
}
```

In which service I can define constants, Should I create separate service? or I have to define same constants in every microservice (like code redundant). I am also using Utility class in monolithic structure same way.

Please explain structure or guide me to define base classes or Utils.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say  3 microservices => you meant 3 different microservice project or 3 different microservices   API in same project ?

Comment: @MyTwoCents - I have implemented 3 different microservice project. in pom.xml all 3 microservices has same Group id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one new module as `Common` and put all your common code in it.

Just add it's dependency in whichever project needed in `pom.xml`.

So even if you run `Microservice1` separately you will have to bind Common module as well in it.

eg in `Microservice1` `pom.xml` add common dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Can [read this as well](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231175/sharing-classes-or-interfaces-between-different-projects)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I got an idea to build structure. I also review SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223505/spring-boot-project-setup-design-decisions?rq=1